# Laravel: Uniquely identify buttons in foreach loop's table

Tags: php, arrays, object, laravel-4, routes

Hi There I have a form where a user can enter some information into forms, which is then stored in a database (posts.sql) All of the previous rows in a table in this database are displayed below this form:

See here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPVOb.png

I am wondering how I could uniquely identify each row's "delete" and "update" button, as the buttons are not parts of the array itself; but just generate in a foreach loop.

Like so

```html
@foreach ($posts as $post)
        <tr>
          <td>{{{ $post->id }}}</td>
          <td>{{{ $post->post_username }}}</td>
          <td>{{{ $post->post_title }}}</td>
          <td>{{{ $post->post_message }}}</td>
          <td><input type="button" onclick="alert('Post Deleted')" value="Delete"></td>
          <td><input type="submit" value="Update"></td>
        </tr>
@endforeach
```

and then perform this function to delete the post.

```php
function delete_post($id)
{
$sql = "delete from posts where id = ?";
DB::delete($sql, array($id));
}
```

and display a new page with the following form where I can update a single row. using a form similar to the one below.

```html
<form method="post" action="{{{ url('update_post_action') }}}">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{{ $post->id }}}">
        <table>
            <tr>
              <td>Post Message</td> 
              <td><input type="text" name="post_message"value="{{{ $post->post_message }}}"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan=2><input type="submit" value="Update item"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
```

Comment: `<button name="delete" value="{{ $post->id }}">Delete</button>`

Comment: @castis Why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: HI there thanks for your response, I was just wondering how i wold reference this new delete button in a function in routes.php?

Answer (score 2):

If you could change your button to this:

```
<button name="delete" value="{{ $post->id }}">Delete</button>
```

then you could use

```
if (isset($_POST['delete']))
{
    delete_post($_POST['delete']);
}
```

Comment: HI there thanks for your response, I was just wondering how i wold reference this new delete button in a function in routes.php?

Comment: if you have a big form around all those elements you would just use `$_POST['delete']` to reference the button.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CRUD routes you will need a form with DELETE action for delete. Update is a simple url like:

```
<a href="posts/{!! $post->id !!}/edit">edit</a>
```

And you can use css to see it like a button.

You can add a form for each row (and action) if you like

I give you a sample with link with javascript submit and button submit sample for post delete.

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
        <tr>
          <td>{{{ $post->id }}}</td>
          <td>{{{ $post->post_username }}}</td>
          <td>{{{ $post->post_title }}}</td>
          <td>{{{ $post->post_message }}}</td>
          <td>
              {!! Form::open(array('method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => array('posts.destroy', $post->id), 'id'=>'post_'.$post->id)) !!}
                <a href="javascript:$('#post_{{$item->id}}').submit();">delete link</a>
                <input type="submit" value="Delete button">
              {!! Form::close() !!}</td>
          <td><input type="submit" value="Update"></td>
        </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Hey there I have this dealio going on now. (I cant use your code exactly because for the assignment minimal logic has to be displayed on home.blade.php So I adapted your idea to this: <form method="post" action="{{{ url('delete_post_action') }}}">
            <button type="submit" value="{{ $post->id }}">Delete</button>
            </form> I am just now confused how to reference this button in routes.php now. Thanks

Comment: Your function needs a parameter so you need to add it in route, or change the controller function and get the id from Request::get('submit'). Your rute sholud be then Route::post('delete_post_action', 'your_controller@delete_post');

Answer (score 0):

Hihi I was able to do this by adding an action to a form within the table and then getting the value of the submit button as a variable in the routes.php file.

home.blade.php

```html
          <td> <!-- Creates a New #Swaggy Button that links to routes to delete item --> 
            <form method="post" action="{{{ url('delete_post_action') }}}">
            <input type="hidden" name="delete_id" value="{{{ $post->id }}}">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete">
            </form>
          </td>
```

routes.php

```php
Route::post('delete_post_action', function()
{   /* Get post->id from hidden input then delete row  */       
    $id = Input::get('delete_id');
    $sql = "delete from posts where id = ?";
    DB::delete($sql, array($id));

    /* Rebuild webpage */ 
    $sql = "select * from posts ORDER BY ID DESC";
    $current_posts = DB::select($sql);
    $results=$current_posts;

      return View::make('pages.home')->withposts($results);
});
```